# Locating MAX Number in a string for a list of records

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am relatively new to JavaScript and trying to get the following achievement.

Lets say we have the following data records.

```
Example data records:
A_ID_R1_V1
A_ID_R1_V2
A_ID_R2_V1
```

Basically I am looking for two results:

1.Create a string based on record A_ID_R1_V2.

```
Input  = A_ID_R1_V2
Output = A_ID_R1_V3
```

My thoughts about this is so locate the MAX V<#> for A_ID_R1_ and then add 1.

2.Create a string based on record A_ID_R2_V1.

```
Input  = A_ID_R2_V1
Output = A_ID_R3_V1
```

My thoughts about this is so locate the MAX R<#> for all records and then add 1.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!!!!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, I don't quite understand the difference between 1. and 2. as both have `A_ID_R1_V#` as input but different output... What would be the result of `magic_function("A_ID_R1_V1")`?

Comment: sry, I updated the description.

Comment: I still don't get it... Are there only these to types of input? And if it is a `_R1_` then the function should increment the number of `V` and if it is a `_R2_` it should increment the number of `R` but not of `V`?

Comment: Lets put it this way: R = Rule, V = Version. One Rule can have 1 or more versions. If I want to add a version for one rule, I would like to get highest version number and add 1. Same for the rules, if I add a new rule, I would like to get the highest rule # and add one and start with version 1.

Comment: Asume we have a `magic_function()`. What would be the input for this function? `A_ID_R1_V1` only? How to distinguish between a new version and a new rule?

Comment: The input could be A_ID_R2_V1, A_ID_R3_V1.. each with different ammounts of versions.
 
Basically the distinction will happen by a click - either on new rule or click on a rules version.

Comment: Where do _all records_ come from? Is it an array in Javascript, a list in the markup, ... - As the requirement isn't meaningful enough to give you a "perfect" solution, this maybe helps you on the next steps... http://jsfiddle.net/3uhsngx3/

Answer (score 0):

try this with regex: http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/wh6n2oqL/

```
newEntry = function(entry){
    var str2 = entry.replace(/\d+$/,'');
    var num = parseInt(entry.replace(/A_ID_R(\d+)_V/,''));
    num = num+1;
    return str2+num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have strong feeling that this is some kind of school homework...

Anyhow, this will do the job, but its not sophisticated nor very effective

```
function updateId(letter){
    var pos = (letter === 'V')?3:2;
    var parts = id.split('_');
    var num = parseInt(parts[pos].substring(1,parts[pos].length));
    parts[pos] = letter+(num+1);

    id = parts.join('_');

    logVal(id);
}
```